# Como faz rotas no Ionic 3 (deep linkings)?

Tags: javascript, ionic3

Gostaria de saber como eu faço com que ao clicar em um botão personalizado, abra minha página com a rota no navegador?

Exemplo na view:

```
<button (click)="sairDaPagina()" class="btn btn-default">Sair</button>
```

**Minha classe:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }

  sairDaPagina() {
    this.navCtrl.push('SairPage');
  }
}
```

**O app.compoment.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { EsqueciMinhaSenhaPage } from '../pages/esqueci-minha-senha/esqueci-minha-senha';
import { SairPage } from '../pages/sair/sair';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  pages: Array<{title:string, component: any}>;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });

    this.pages = [
      {title:"Página inicial", component:HomePage},
      {title:"Esqueci minha senha", component:EsqueciMinhaSenhaPage},
      {title:"Sair", component:SairPage}
    ];
}
}
```

> **Obs:** Não estou nem conseguindo exibir a URL

Para poder acessar, tive que adicionar na minha classe:

```
import { SairPage } from '../../pages/sair/sair';
```

E mudar isso:

```
 sairDaPagina() {
    this.navCtrl.push(SairPage);
 }
```

Só que não consegui ainda exibir a URL.